# Convert wide table into long table selecting columns with "start_with"

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have a table that looks like this:

| Z1 | R1 | Z2 | R2 | ... | Z100 | R100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1246 | 1 | 2986 | 3 | ... | 3163 | 4 |
| 2734 | 5 | 1066 | 7 | ... | 2645 | 8 |

Its a wide table that I want to convert into a long table like that:

| Z | Time in ms | R | Reaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Z1 | 1246 | R1 | 1 |
| Z1 | 2734 | R1 | 5 |
| Z2 | 2986 | R2 | 3 |
| Z2 | 1066 | R2 | 7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Z100 | 3163 | R100 | 4 |
| Z100 | 2645 | R100 | 8 |

I tried this:

```
data_time_config_long <- data_time_config %>%
  gather(key = "Z", value = "Time in ms", select(data_time_config, starts_with('Z'))) %>%
  gather(key = "R", value = "Reaction", select(data_time_config, starts_with('R')))
```

And i get this error:

```
Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector. x Subscript has the wrong type `tbl_df< Z1 : double Z2 : double Z3 : double Z4 : double Z5 : double Z6 : double Z7 : double Z8 : double Z9 : double Z10 : double Z11 : double Z12 : double Z13 : double Z14 : double Z15 : double Z16 : double Z17 : double Z18 : double Z19 : double Z20 : double Z21 : double Z22 : double Z23 : double Z24 : double Z25 : double Z26 : double Z27 : double Z28 : double Z29 : double Z30 : double Z31 : double Z32 : double Z33 : double Z34 : double Z35 : double Z36 : double Z37 : double Z38 : double Z39 : double Z40 : double Z41 : double Z42 : double Z43 : double Z44 : double Z45 : double Z46 : double Z47 : double Z48 : double Z49 : double Z50 : double Z51 : double Z52 : double Z53 : double Z54 : double Z55 : double Z56 : double Z57 : double Z58 : double Z59 : double Z60
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not directly solvable with tidyr::gather(), which is depricated and one should use tidyr::pivot_longer(). My approach would be this:

```
library(tidyverse)

#dummy data
df <- data.frame(Z1 = c(1246,2734), R1 = c(1,5), 
                 Z2 = c(2986,1066), R2 = c(3,7),
                 Z100 = c(3163,2645), R100 = c(4,8))

# intermediate data.frame
idf <- df %>%
   # add row numbers as we need them to keep the order
  dplyr::mutate(rn = dplyr::row_number()) %>%
  # gather is depricated
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-rn, names_to = "colu", values_to = "vals") %>%
  # extract number from the column names that now are a column as we need them to keep the order also
  dplyr::mutate(nr = readr::parse_number(colu))

# select columns with Z and join columns with R acording to row number and numeric part of column names
idf %>%
  dplyr::filter(stringr::str_detect(colu, "Z")) %>%
  dplyr::left_join(idf %>%
                     dplyr::filter(stringr::str_detect(colu, "R")), by = c("rn", "nr")) %>%
  # order to get the exact output you are looking for
  dplyr::arrange(nr) %>%
  # select and rename to get exactout put you a looking vor
  dplyr::select(Z = colu.x, `Time in ms` = vals.x, R = colu.y, Reaction = vals.y) 

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Z     `Time in ms` R     Reaction
  <chr>        <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1 Z1            1246 R1           1
2 Z1            2734 R1           5
3 Z2            2986 R2           3
4 Z2            1066 R2           7
5 Z100          3163 R100         4
6 Z100          2645 R100         8
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
df <- data.frame(Z1 = c(1246,2734), R1 = c(1,5), 
                 Z2 = c(2986,1066), R2 = c(3,7),
                 Z100 = c(3163,2645), R100 = c(4,8))

library(dplyr)
df |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c(".value", "Ind"), names_pattern = "(.)(\\d.*)") |> 
  rename(`Time in ms` = Z, Reaction = R) |> 
  mutate(Z = paste0("Z", Ind), R = paste0("R", Ind)) |> 
  select(Z, `Time in ms`, R, Reaction)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Z     `Time in ms` R     Reaction
  <chr>        <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1 Z1            1246 R1           1
2 Z2            2986 R2           3
3 Z100          3163 R100         4
4 Z1            2734 R1           5
5 Z2            1066 R2           7
6 Z100          2645 R100         8
```